# Bootstrap Popover and Tooltip is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I did every thing possible but i could not make it work.

Popover and Tooltip in Bootstrap just work fine for the first time and after that they appears and disappears quickly. Is there any thing I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
<input type="text" title="test"  id="disclaimer" style="height:40px" />

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#disclaimer').popover(
        {
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            placement: 'right',

            container: 'body',
            delay:"1000"
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this sample :

```
$('#disclaimer').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    delay: { 
        show: 500, 
        hide: 1500
    },
}).hover();
```